What is the XPath query to return a defined element
I'm trying to retrieve the value "TEST RESULTS FROM RESPONSE" from the response XML shown below. This has been returned from an API call made via SOAP.
I need to query the value in the element <wsOut>, but for the life of me I can't quite seem to get there....
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <runResponse xmlns="urn:TestAPI:testingtestingAPI">
      <result xsi:nil="true" />
      <wsOut>TEST RESULTS FROM RESPONSE</wsOut>
    </runResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

The XPath queries I've tried are...
/SOAP-ENV-Envelope/SOAP:ENV:Body/runResponse/
/SOAP-ENV-Envelope/SOAP:ENV:Body/runResponse[0]
/SOAP-ENV-Envelope/SOAP:ENV:Body/runResponse/wsOut

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :-)

What's the language/tool used to test the xpath?

After a run, and a swim I worked it out...
//*[local-name()='wsReturn']

Your XPath queries don't work because you're blatantly ignoring the XML namespace (xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/") defined in your XML document

Chose one of the zillions of questions on this topic to mark this as a duplicate.

This worked well
//*[local-name()='wsReturn']

